# How to create a blueprint for new classes

Tags: java, interface, abstract

To improve my knowledge about coding I want to build a library with as much patterns, containers and simular stuff as possible.

I don't want to implement the patterns itself but rather want to describe them. For example, I don't want the library to contain an observer but rather when the main project requires an observer, I can just add `extends observer` or `implements observer` and the IDE should auto-complete it as far as possible.

To start of easy (atleast I thought so) I wanted to start with the (anti-)pattern for a Singleton.

I created an Interface `iSingleton { iSingleton getInstance(); }`, together with an abstract class

```
public abstract class Singleton implements iSingleton
{
    static Singleton instance;

    protected Singleton() {}
}
```

and of course I created an implementation test class

```
public class Test extends Singleton
{
    private Test();

    public Test getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Test();
        }

        return (Test) instance;
    }
}
```

However this gave a few issues

- I didn't have to create `private Test`
- Test test = Test.getInstance(); cannot be called from non-static context
- I have to cast the return value in getInstance

What I want is a class/interface that tells and allows me to build something like this

```
public Implementation extends/implements Singleton
{
    static Implementation instance;

    private Implementation()
    {
        // It's a singleton, use getInstance()
    }

    public static Implementation getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Implementation()
        }

        return instance
    }
}
```

The specifics I would like

- tell the implementation class to have a (static) variable of itself
- tell the implementation class to have a private constructor
- tell the implementation class to have a static method called getInstance

How can I create something like and is it even possible?

Comment: "and of course I created an implementation test class" if you can create a subclass, it's not a singleton!

Comment: By far the easiest way to create a class of which there is only ever a single instance is with an enum; and enums can implement interfaces. But it's not clear to me what you think a "singleton interface" would be: you cannot stop there being more than one implementation of a public interface, so that interface cannot represent something of which there is a single instance.

Comment: @AndyTurner I guess there is some confusion with the word interface. An interface tells a method this object is build like this. But I don't want that, I want to tell my IDE (to tell me) this class should be build like this. The "singleton interface" should not be an active object in the application, it's only for the IDE. For example, let's say I making a blueprint for a door. I don't want to tell the house owner the door should have/has a door latch, I want to inform construction worker that a door contains at least a door latch so that it's suitable for usage.

Comment: @AndyTurner in that situation the is no actual door. There is only a blueprint. The house owner doesn't has a door yet. The construction worker does now however know what a door should look like, how he can operate it. In the case of the singleton. Me (or any other developer that accesses my project) doesn't have a singleton yet, but when he uses the blueprint, he is told the singleton should look like this.